# How to generate bytecode and save to .class file?

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode

I have the following weird requirement.

I am given:

1. A list of some method names.
2. Names and types of parameters of the above methods.
3. The functionality of the above methods. This is as follows:
   For each parameter, the method converts it to string using `toString` and obtains an array of strings. To this array, the method applies a function `foo`. The function `foo` takes as input a `String []` type and outputs `String`. The methods return what `foo` returns.
   `foo`'s code is given inside a Java object and is to be accessed as a black-box.

The info in 1. and 2. can be in a text or XML file. For this purpose, we can consider it to be available inside a Java object in whatever way we choose.

The task is to create a `.class` file (i.e., bytecode) that implements those methods and can be run on the JVM.

I think [this assembler library](http://asm.ow2.org/) would be one way to do it. Can anyone suggest an easier way?

[EDIT:] I can think of one other way: first generate the `.java` file and then compile it to get the `.class` file.

[The context:] I have to do this for several hundreds of methods. I want the shortcut so I can automate my job rather than manually write the code.

Comment: Could you please give more context, what do you want to achieve... The only reason I see for "making" specific methods for a generic behaviour (foo) is type safety which is helpful at compile time... How are you going to use / call the generated code ?

Comment: I won't call the generated code. What I want to do is make a API library (jar) for someone to use. The class will be of a specific name, so they will know which API to call.

Comment: OK I see the problem with hundreds of methods, will the list of methods change often or not ? can we have an example of the input you are using ?

Comment: @pgras: I will shortly give a sample file.

Comment: @pgras: It may not change often but it will definitely change once in a while and that is enough to cause headaches in keeping the two in sync if I handcode them. [Edit: the data file to read is generated in an automated way that reads methods and outputs their types, so it makes sense to do the reverse also via an automated way]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could generate the required program code in Java syntax and turn it into a class file using the compiler. It's possible to instantiate `javac` at run time and pass it a byte array instead of the location of the source file. This is probably the easiest for other programmers to maintain.

If you want to generate byte code directly, [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) is the library most commonly used.

Comment: I think this would probably be the most convenient way (generating the `.java` file).

Comment: Can you give some info on how to do this via `javac` assuming I have created the .java file?

Comment: It's in the `javax.tools` package. This article has an example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/index.html . I must admit that I haven't used the `javax.tools` API myself.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a list of Open Source ByteCode Libraries: http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries

Have a look at [Javassist](http://labs.jboss.com/javassist/).

Answer (score 0):

I saw you answer to my comment, but it is still not clear for me why you want to generate the code to be then packaged in a jar, just type it :)

Now if you want a typesafe api with all method having the same behaviour you could provide a dynamic proxy for a given interface (this leaves you with the question on how to generate the interface :)

Here is an example where all the calls to all the MyInterface method will be handled by the invoke method (just add methods to the interface to test it)...

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class Test {

interface MyInterface {

    String methodOne(String s);

    String methodTwo(String s, Integer i);
}

static MyInterface proxy = (MyInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        MyInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[] { MyInterface.class }, new InvocationHandler() {
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                    throws Throwable {  
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                for (Object arg : args) {
                    result.append(arg.toString());
                }
                return result.toString();
            }
        });

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(proxy.methodOne("hello"));       
    System.out.println(proxy.methodTwo("world", 5));

}   

}
```

Comment: If I could type that much, there would not have been a need to ask the question :-). I use Scala primarily because I don't like typing.